# how to set the height of a table that needs to be a percentage based on a parent's percentage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that I need to be a percentage.  The problem is the parent is also a percentage.  Currently the setting is ignored.  Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad8nzs1v/11/).  clicking on the button next to the whole number textbox will expand the header.  But the table does not fit.  I can not hard code the value because the user can resize the form.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
<body>

    <header id='header'>

        <br>
        <form id='reload' name="Actions" action="Viewer.php" method="post">
            <div id='WholeNumberSection'>
                Whole Number
                <input type="hidden" id='Print' name="Print">
                <input type="text" id='WholeNumber'>
                <input type="button" onclick="toggleDropdown()"/> 
                <div id="WholeNumberTable"><Table id="WholeNumberList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="2">
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS9230</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'></TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>BAC5009</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>J</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>S6112-23025</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>AE</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SER-65109</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>B</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS8640</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>17</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>S6132-61009</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>D</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS8618</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>4</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>70553-01108</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>J</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS8630</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>20</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>S6110-26102</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>W</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>65652-11146</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>S</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS9999</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>62</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS9208</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>30</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS9208</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>43</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>HP1-1</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>R</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS8805</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>6</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>70216-01007</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>AB</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>SS8486</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>11</TD></TR>
<TR><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>70009-02001</TD><TD class='WholeNumberCell'>M</TD></TR></Table></div>   
        </div>
    </form>

</header>

<div id="sidebar">
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>

<footer>

        <br>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem line has been marked in this function:
    function toggleDropdown()
    {

```
    if (document.getElementById('header').style.height == '' || document.getElementById('header').style.height == "60px") 
    {
        document.getElementById('header').style.height='60%';
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.top='60%';
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height='calc(40% - 60px)';
        document.getElementById('content').style.top='60%';
        document.getElementById('content').style.height='calc(40% - 60px)';
        document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('WholeNumberTable').style.width='256px' ;
        //Problem line
        document.getElementById('WholeNumberTable').style.height='calc(40% - 260px)' ;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById('header').style.height='60px';
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.top='60px';
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height='calc(100% - 120px)';
        document.getElementById('content').style.top='60px';
        document.getElementById('content').style.height='calc(100% - 120px)';
        document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.display = "none";              }
    }
```

Here is the css

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #013499;
    margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #7690C5;
    bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
    top: 60px;
    width: 200px;
}

#content {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    height: calc(100% - 120px);
    overflow: auto;
    top: 60px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    margin: -60px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #013499;
}

#buttons {
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

#dropDownButton {
    vertical-align: -5px;
}

#ImgeDataTable {
    border-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#WholeNumber {
    width: 135px;
}

#WholeNumberSection {
    color: white;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

#WholeNumberList {
    color: white;
    display: none;
    height: inherit;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.WholeNumberCell {
    color: #000000;
}

#WholeNumberTable {
    height: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.send_button {
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}

.small {
    width: 50px;
}
.medium {
    width: 200px;
}
.large {
    width: 400px;
}
.scrollingTable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `WholeNumberTable` doesn't exist as an element.

Comment: Cut and paste error.  It has been corrected.

Comment: If I hardcode the value to say '200px' it works.  But it looks like crap when resized / viewed on a machine with a different resolution.

Comment: You also can't reuse an ID more than once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I corrected it.  But I still can not get the dropdown to resize.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your ID of WholeNumberCell to a class, and it worked fine for me

All of your elements in the table with an Id of WholeNumberCell need to be changed to a class of WholeNumberCell. An Id is unique and can only be applied to one element, where as a class can be applied to many elements.

In addition, any CSS referencing 
    #WholeNumberCell
should now be
     .WholeNumberCell

'#' is for Ids, and '.' is for classes

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I corrected it however the dropdown still does not resize based on percentage.

Comment: I updated the link.  I was cleaning up the code a bit and found when I change the '#' to a '.' for WholeNumberCell it does not work even though I changed the selector from 'id' to 'class'.  But it does work with with 'class='WholeNumberCell' in the HTML and #WholeNumberCell in the CSS.  I'm gonna have to update my source to see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

```
                    document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.height=document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight-60 + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

1 other solution could be to make a mathematical formula which calculates the height of the header from the number of rows in the table. Here is the modified version of the javascript code, which uses this trick:

```
function toggleDropdown()
    {           
        var numRows = document.getElementById('WholeNumberTable').getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
        var headerHeight = (70*parseInt(numRows))/19.00;

        if (document.getElementById('header').style.height == '' || document.getElementById('header').style.height == "60px") 
            {
                document.getElementById('header').style.height=headerHeight+'%';
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.top='60%';
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height='calc(40% - 60px)';
                document.getElementById('content').style.top='60%';
                document.getElementById('content').style.height='calc(40% - 60px)';
                document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.width='156px' ;
                //document.getElementById('WholeNumberTable').style.height='calc(40% - 160px)' ;//Problem line
            }
        else 
            {
                document.getElementById('header').style.height='60px';
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.top='60px';
                document.getElementById('sidebar').style.height='calc(100% - 120px)';
                document.getElementById('content').style.top='60px';
                document.getElementById('content').style.height='calc(100% - 120px)';
                document.getElementById('WholeNumberList').style.display = "none";        
            }           
    }
```

I used 70 in the formula because according to the number of rows, i.e. 19, in the table 70% height of the header seems to fit appropriately. And rest is simple maths. 
You should also modify the css a little bit for div "wholeNumberTable" :

```
 #WholeNumberTable {
  /*height: 0;*/
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

No need to set the div height explicitly, the default height of this div will be equal to the: *height of the table + padding*.